# Simple Scoring Setup for List

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, formula

I am trying to set up a list with a scoring system that I currently use in Excel. I use the Excel sheet as a form with a series of yes/no questions. 100 points is the maximum amount and each question is worth varied deductions if a "no" answer is given.

In Excel I use...

=MAX(0,1-IF(E7="No",0.25,0)-IF(E8="No",0.25,0))

I tried to use this same formula by just putting the column names in where the cells were…

=MAX(0,1-IF([Question 01]="No",0.25,0)-IF([Question 02]="No",0.25,0))

No errors, it just doesn’t work. The scores remain at 100%

I have also tried…

=MAX(0,1-IF([Question 01]="False",0.25,0)-IF([Question 02]="False",0.25,0))

No errors, it just doesn’t work. All the other variations I try give errors. I even tried making a column called [Base Score] and giving it a value of 100 and that didn’t work either.
I’m fairly new to this, but I’m stumped. Any help would be greatly apricated.

Comment: Hi, please try this in parts, i.e. check if your IF conditions are returning values properly by keeping only the IF condition in the formula. Also, open the list item in edit mode and save, without making any changes, formulas are not applied unless there is some update on the data.

Comment: Thank you, I really do appreciate you trying to help me. I finally figured out how to make it work. There was nothing wrong with the formula, I had the "Question 01" set as yes/no. I simply changed it to choice/choose from a list and put yes and no as the choices. Now, it works perfectly. :)